Using Entra ID and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient within SSAS (Analysis Services)
I'm trying to use Entra ID and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient within a multi-dimensional SSAS model (Analysis Services). When I deploy my cube and try to process it, I get the following error:
Errors in the back-end database access module. The managed provider 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' could not be instantiated. Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
Has anyone been able to use Entra ID in a data source in a multi-dimensional SSAS model? TIA.

https://devcodef1.com/news/1264734/entraid-and-microsoft-data-sqlclient-in-ssas#:~:text=To%20use%20EntraID%20Microsoft.Data.SqlClient%20in%20a%20multi-dimensional%20SSAS,the%20data%20source.%20Deploy%20and%20process%20the%20cube.
